# How to download build output files from jenkins UI console itself

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am new Jenkins , using  **jenkins 1.651.3**   War  deployed  on **Tomcat6**
Is there any way to download  Jenkins job’s output  file ( my job produced a jar file ) from jenkins UI Console  itself ?

So, could anyone suggest me is there any way or plugin available to make the each Jenkins build output files ( like Jar/War) as downloadable from the Jenkins server machine

```
 [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ NumberGenerator ---
    [INFO] Building jar: /opt/cloudhost/jenkinsHome/jobs/TestGiby/workspace/NumberGenerator/target/NumberGenerator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ NumberGenerator ---
    [INFO] Installing /opt/cloudhost/jenkinsHome/jobs/TestGiby/workspace/NumberGenerator/target/NumberGenerator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /opt/cloudhost/software/maven/mavenRepo/com/giby/maven/NumberGenerator/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/NumberGenerator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    [INFO] Installing /opt/cloudhost/jenkinsHome/jobs/TestGiby/workspace/NumberGenerator/pom.xml to /opt/cloudhost/software/maven/mavenRepo/com/giby/maven/NumberGenerator/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/NumberGenerator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 2.575 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-01T05:00:44+00:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 19M/607M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `Archive the artifacts` post-build step, it copies the selected artifacts in the artifacts folder.

[image: Archive the artifacts build step]

Then you will be able to download the file from build page itself.

[image: Download build artifacts]

For Pipeline you need to add it in the pipeline script itself. Check for the corresponding groovy script for archive the artifacts or find the below example (this is a working code).

```
post {
    always {
            archive "project/embsw/debug/**/*"
           stash includes: 'project/embsw/debug/project_R0.bin', name: 'debugBuiltArtifacts'
           }
    }
```

Comment: I can't see post build options for jenkins pipelines

Comment: @SibiCoder for pipeline you need to add it in the pipeline script itself. Check for the corresponding groovy script for archive the artifacts.

Answer (score 8):

Well, you can right click on "View as unformatted text" and choose "Save link as" to save log on your PC.

Answer (score 6):

I am able to directly open the console log in Notepad++.  Just right-click the "Full Log" link, copy the link address, then paste it into the "Open" dialog in Notepad++.

[image: "Full Log" link]

[image]

My Jenkins server had to be configured to allow this.

Comment: Nice solution, works like a charm, beware that if the console output is very large, this can hang your Notepad++

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone is searching how to enable this option in a Jenkinsfile, I will put an example down where I do a backup of a single table from a MariaDB database and then download it from the job build :)

```
stage('Backup') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "rm -rf db.dump.sql*"
                    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'my-database-credentials', passwordVariable: 'DB_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'DB_USERNAME')]) {
                        sh """docker run --rm -t \
                            -v $WORKSPACE:/data \
                            --entrypoint mysqldump \
                            mariadb -v \
                            -P 3306 \
                            -h ${DB_HOST} \
                            -u master \
                            --password="${DB_PASSWORD}" \
                            --default-character-set=latin1 \
                            --skip-lock-tables --skip-add-locks \
                            --single-transaction --add-drop-table --complete-insert \
                            --result-file="/data/db.dump.sql" ${DATABASE_NAME} ${TABLE_NAME}"""
                    }
                    sh "du -sh db.dump.sql"
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'db.dump.sql', excludes: 'output/*.md'
                }
            }
        }
```

Just add the following line in your Jenkinsfile script

`archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'db.dump.sql', excludes: 'output/*.md'`

[image]

Reference: [test and artifacts](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/)