# Provide access to workspace files in log while Jenkins Build is running

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pause, artifact

We want to have a pipeline, that builds our application than pauses and after the built application was manually tested resumes and delivers the tested application.

So I came up with the idea of using a Input to pause the pipeline like this:

```
...
stage ("Build"){
    // build application here and archive it as artefact
}
timeout(time:5, unit:'DAYS') {
    input message:'Approve deployment?'
}
stage ("Deliver"){
   // deliver the built application
}
```

The tester got 5 days to test the application then resumes the pipeline and it gets delivered.

My problem here is, while the build is still running, the tester can't yet access the artifact on the status page.

So is there any way to provide any kind of Download-Link in the log output, that points to the application file I archived in the build stage?
Or is there any other good way to achieve this build->pause->test->resume->deliver workflow in one single pipeline job?

Automation of the test in the pipeline is not an option, as the application needs to be manually flashed on some hardware.

Comment: why don't you split the pipeline in 2? before the manual work and after manual work? (or 2 jobs - depending on what you are doing there)

Comment: It's a customer requirement. I know 2 pipelines would be easier, but we're told to at least try to find a solution to do it within one.

Comment: then maybe you can create a "fake" job test and leave it run until the tester finishes his test and then in the delivery you can use this plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin to check if the fake test job is running. When the tester finishes his test he can then manually end the fake job. But this is a nasty way of resolving this and it may cause problems in the future (mainly due to the human err :p).

Comment: Manually resuming the job is not an issue, as I can do this with the pause. My need is to access the artifacts of the job easily while it is still running(paused).

Comment: yes that's the reason I said you need to create another job "fake-test". So you will have 3 jobs: 1. build and create artifacts -> 2. fake-test and wait 3. deploy. When you are in job 3 and waiting for 2. you already have all the artifacts (if you use maven to store them in an artifactory or something like that you will have them available)

Comment: That will be an additional job on top of a second one which I'd already like to avoid. So my question is still the same, can I provide artifacts in an easy way while the job is still running? I update the question to account for only one pipelinejob.

Comment: how does your pipeline looks like in jenkins? can you get to a page of the build and see the artifacts (like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41974070/how-to-download-build-output-files-from-jenkins-ui-console-itself?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) ?

Comment: No, the artifacts on the build page are not available on status page until the build is finished.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you to the artifacts list (you can add more after `artifact` if you want the link to point to the specific file):

```
...
timeout(time:5, unit:'DAYS') {
    echo "Archive available for download: ${env.BUILD_URL}artifact"
    input message:'Approve deployment?'
}
```

This requires the value of `JENKINS_URL` to be set in the system configuration: From  your Jenkins home, click on **Manage Jenkins** --> **Configure System** and look for the **Jenkins URL** under **Jenkins Location**

If you don't have admin access to Jenkins, and `JENKINS_URL` is not set, you could fudge this with something like

```
https://known-jenkins-url/job/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}/artifact
```